# Call private method using MyBase

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have .net webforms project written in vb.net with no access to the compiled DLL file.

In ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="000" CodeBehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="000._default6"  EnableEventValidation = "false"%>
```

I need to call a method available in the class 000._default6, so I tried to add the following line to the ASPX file

```
<% MyBase.sendnow() %>
```

but it is throwing an error:

> sendnow() is not a member of _default6

Any possibility to call that private method from ASPX?

Comment: Using reflection.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you, I tried to google that before posting the question but I didn't find the answer! can you help, please?

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21899504

Comment: Thank you @VisualVincent, I read your example and I'm wondering how to pass the parameters if we assume that the method is accepting two Strings?

Comment: Pass them as an array of objects as the second parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VisualVincent,  I created an array with two Strings, and passed that array as a parameter, I got an error saying ( Parameter count mismatch ) but I'm 100% sure that my method is accepting two parameters as Strings only! What do you think?

Comment: Please show me the method's definition and how you are calling it.

Comment: @VisualVincent, the method definition is "Private Sub sendemail(ByVal b_email As String, ByVal b_name As String)", I'm calling the method as per your example I created an array of string "Dim arrayOfStrings() As String
        arrayOfStrings = {"email@email.com", "name"}"  and then calling the function "method1.Invoke(obj, New Object() {arrayOfStrings})"

Comment: Each parameter is represented by an item in the _object array_. Your current code assumes the method structure `sendemail(Arg As String())`. Instead you should be calling it like: `method1.Invoke(obj, New Object() {"email@email.com", "name"})`

Comment: Thank you @VisualVincent, But my method sendemail is located in compiled DLL file where I don't have an access to modify it! any way to overcome that?

Comment: You're not supposed to modify it! The first was just an example of what your code _was trying to do_ because **each item** inside `New Object() {...}` represents **one argument**. So if your method has two arguments, you've got to pass them like: `New Object() {arg1, arg2}`, _**not**_ as an array.

Comment: Perfect @VisualVincent, I misunderstood your explanation, I call it in the same way you instructed and I think we passed the previous issue (parameters count mismatch), Now I'm getting (Object reference not set to an instance of an object), I google it and I found that it is a very general error! any idea about that?

Comment: It is thrown when an object is null (Nothing). Usually it's when you've forgot to initialize a variable using `New`. In your case it is either caused by the `sendemail()` method, or by your code. How have you declared `obj`?

Comment: Hi @VisualVincent, the is the way I declared it `Dim obj As New 123._default Dim objType = obj.GetType() Dim method1 = objType.GetMethod("sendemail", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)` But I mostly think that `sendemail()` is throwing that error but I'm not sure!

Comment: It would appear so, yes.

Comment: If you want to call a method located in the _current_ class (or in one of its parents, since you were using `MyBase`) just set `Dim obj = Me`.